# Private key encryption that is not CPA secure

Tags: chosen-plaintext-attack

I've been learning about different types of encryption schemes in class and I was wondering if it's possible to create a private-key encryption scheme that **is** multi-message secure but **is NOT** CPA-secure?

It seems that CPA security implies multi-message CPA security, but what about the other way? For example if given a private key multi-message secure scheme what changes would need to be made to ensure it's not CPA secure?

Comment: Doesn't multi-message security include CPA security?

Comment: It would help (at least me) if you give the definition of "multi-message secure" that you assume. While the definition of CPA-secure is standard enough, it could help (you) to also write it, if only to see the difference. These kind of things are mostly about properly grasping definitions.

Comment: See the bottom page 70 of Lindell&Katz book edition 3. The implication is clear!

Comment: Ah, that explains the remark about private key encryption instead of symmetric encryption, as that book mess up the definition of secret and private keys.